# How to rec video from v4l2 and decode to vp9 with gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2, vp9

My pipeline
`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! avdec_vp9 ! filesink location=vid.webm`

It will error:
`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link v4l2src0 to avdec_vp9-0`

Whats wrong?

Comment: When im use `parsebin` between `v4l2src` and `avdec_vp9` pipeline is correct, but give another error `Missing decoder: Uncompressed packed YUV decoder`.
All plugins installed

Comment: v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --list-formats-ext 
http://pastebin.com/QFFB27Hn

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline works:
`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! vp9enc ! webmmux ! filesink location='raw_dual.webm' sync=false`